# Using pre-commit tool, is there a way to pass filenames one by one to the `entry` program?

Tags: git, powershell, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

Using [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/), I'm trying to invoke [`PSScriptAnalyzer`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) tool as a static checker for PowerShell scripts.
Since there is no pre-commit *language* for PowerShell and I don't want to add an additional script to the repository for this simple task, I have to resort to `system` language and call `pwsh` as a pre-installed system command.

I also don't want to run the checker as `PSScriptAnalyzer -Recurse -Path .` because I don't want git-ignored files or files which are not modified and are not part of the changeset to also be checked.

So I have come up with the following snippet in my `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file:

```
- repo: local
  hooks:
    - id: PSScriptAnalyzer
      name: Check Powershell scripts with PSScriptAnalyzer
      language: system
      entry: pwsh -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -EnableExit -Path 
      files: ^.*\.ps1$
      pass_filenames: true
```

The problem is this command can only handle one argument being passed to it but pre-commit passes any matching file at the end of the command as arguments, resulting in an error.

pre-commit [does not seem to have an option](https://pre-commit.com/#arguments-pattern-in-hooks) to change this behavior and pass the files individually. The host is Linux and latest versions of pre-commit and pwsh are installed inside.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pre-commit intentionally does not support one-file-at-a-time because it is grossly inefficient (starting and stopping a process (or more) per file is quite slow).

ideally the other tool (PSScriptAnalyzer) would be adjusted to support passing multiple arguments (since this will have benefits outside of pre-commit, such as usage with `xargs`)

that said, you can hack around this deficiency in whatever tool you're trying to use with pre-commit via a little bit of `xargs` -- converting the sequence of arguments into individual calls

[here](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/394#issuecomment-588562966) is the oldest duplicate in the issue tracker and outlines the solution (you can probably adapt the `bash` solution to `powershell` or utilize `xargs -n1` if you don't care about spaces):

```yaml
    entry: bash -c 'for x in "$@"; do ... "$x"; done' --
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit